# Boost threads unavailable on this platform compile error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, boost, boost-thread

I am writing a program that have to use the library boost/thread. I install the library with macports on my os X lion. I include in my project under eclipse the library and then I compile my program. I have this error Boost threads unavailable on this platform.
In a post I have read that I have to use -pthread flag under GCC C++ -> Miscellaneous -> other flags, but I have the same error.
Any idea?
thanks

Comment: How exactly is the error message, where do you see the error message and how do you compiled your code?